# ListView of bitmaps runs out of memory

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory

I let the user draw stuff on an ImageView and click save to save the drawing. Later the user can see all saved drawings in a ListView that has an ImageView and two TextViews with some detalis.

To avoid saving and retrieving bitmaps I store all the x-y points that were drawn in a txt file and recreate the bitmaps while populating the list using createBitmap method drawing the points and setting the bitmap on the ImageView inside the Adapter.

When the user deletes or updates the list i finish and restart the list activity to reload the file and all those bitmaps are recreated but the previous are not recycled because i don't know where to call the recycle method !!

So naturally the problem is that sometimes i get OutOfMemory error because of all the bitmaps.
QUESTION: where can i call recycle for the bitmaps or how else can i implement this without using so much memory
this is the list adapter

```
public class CustomGalleryListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
private final Activity context;
private final String[] name_plus_details;
private final String[] imageinfo;
public CustomGalleryListAdapter(Activity context,
String[] name_plus_details, String[] imageinfo) {
super(context, R.layout.gallery_list_single_item_layout, name_plus_details);
this.context = context;
this.name_plus_details = name_plus_details;
this.imageinfo = imageinfo;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    Paint mPaint,mPaint2;
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(23/4);

    mPaint2 = new Paint();
    mPaint2.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint2.setDither(true);
    mPaint2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    mPaint2.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint2.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint2.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint2.setStrokeWidth(17/4);


    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    Bitmap mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(600/5, 700/5, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
    String[] imagedata = imageinfo[position].split(":");
    String[] points;
    for(int i=0;i<imagedata.length;i++){
        if(imagedata[i].contains(";")){
            points=imagedata[i].split(";");
            if(points[0].length()>0){
                int drawx1 = Integer.parseInt(points[0].split(",")[0]);
                int drawy1 = Integer.parseInt(points[0].split(",")[1]);
                mCanvas.drawCircle(drawx1/5, drawy1/5, 15/4, mPaint2);
            }
            for(int h=0;h+1<points.length-1;h++){
                int drawx1 = Integer.parseInt(points[h].split(",")[0]);
                int drawy1 = Integer.parseInt(points[h].split(",")[1]);
                int drawx2 = Integer.parseInt(points[h+1].split(",")[0]);
                int drawy2 = Integer.parseInt(points[h+1].split(",")[1]);
                mCanvas.drawLine(drawx1/5, drawy1/5, drawx2/5, drawy2/5, mPaint);
            }
        }
    }
    View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_list_single_item_layout, null, true);
    TextView detailsTextView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
    TextView name_field = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.gallery_name_field);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getContext().getResources(),mBitmap));
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);      
    imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
    String[] text_parts = name_plus_details[position].split("ENDNAME");
    name_field.setText(text_parts[0]);
    detailsTextView.setText("\n"+text_parts[1]);

    return rowView;

}
}
```

Comment: Try to reuse your row layout. Do not inflate it at all getView call. It is very normal to get out of memory error with your implementation at getView.

Comment: i apologize but i didn't quite get that..could you explain a bit more? when you usay "reuse row layout" you mean free the list items that are not currently on screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using holders so that you don't inflate your view for every cell since you are just reusing them. Check this out: http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder
There are also tons of examples in the web telling you how to use a holder in an ArrayAdapter

Comment: i'm a begginer in android so i guess i have homework to do. i will check it out but please tell me... in what way will your approach save memory? i still have to create the bitmaps for the whole list so what changes?

Comment: I suppose if you use a holder your memory will improve dramatically. Just test it an let me know

Comment: i don't dissagree..i just want to understand the concept better. (just in case you didn't notice i don't have the bitmaps stored as bitmaps. i recreate them programmatically)

Comment: Yes but right now you are also recreating the whole view which is very memory consuming

Comment: so your approach solves some other problem of my code. not the recycling bitmaps problem.

Comment: i tried your approach and even for a large number of bitmaps (tried up to 130!!) i had no memory problem. thnx for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

First - read this:
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

I think, that it allows you to save much memory as far as I understand you have made something like atlas for your bitmaps - this looks much better.

Using this solution will give you also a very convenient way to dispose bitmaps:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html#entryRemoved(boolean, K, V, V)